# PHP: Send raw IMAP (get email range)

Tags: php, email, imap, fetch

I'm trying to fetch an interval of emails from IMAP like so:

> UID FETCH 1:20

But none of the functions native to PHP allow me to do that.

Any ideas?

Comment: have you checked http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imap-open.php ?

Comment: yeah... it doesnt do that